# Can I skip "if" statement with chrome debugger or another javascript debugger?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, javascript, web

I see this code in a bug bounty program

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
<script>
if(window.location.pathname === '/' || window.location.pathname.includes('.html')){
            window.location='/not_here';
}
else {
    console.log("how can i be here?")
}
</script>
```

The page has no "index.php"

How can I get into the `console.log()` or don't go to `/not_here`

Comment: Download the HTML file, delete the if statement and then open it with a browser.

Comment: wont work, the code has xhr and xhr work only at the same domain

Comment: Use a proxy to modify the response and remove the condition. However, this will not get you a bug bounty. Why does it matter though? Why can't you just trigger whatever is in the else condition manually?

Comment: this would be better cos ther are a lot of requests